# Are all the paired sentences grammatically correct? And do all those sound natural to native speakers?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-usage

I am an English teacher who has a duty to teach correct English to the students who want to learn it. That is why I think I have to know grammatically correct English because it can destroy my students' lives if I teach them wrong or incorrect English. And one of my students asked me which of the two is correct or if both are correct. But for me, passive sentences sound unnatural, but I am not sure about that. That is why I am asking native speakers or grammarians which of the two is grammatically correct or which of the two sounds more natural to native speaker.

1. The car is too old to repair. 
   =The car is so old that we cannot repair it.
2. The car is too old to be repaired. 
   =The car is so old that it cannot be repaired.
3. The coffee is too hot to drink. 
   =The coffee is so hot that we cannot drink it.
4. The coffee is too hot to be drunk. 
   =The coffee is so hot that it cannot be drunk.
5. Microbeads are too small to filter out during the waste water treatment process.
   =Microbeads are so small that we can not filter them out during the waste water treatment process
6. Microbeads are too small to be filtered out during the waste water treatment process.
   =Microbead are so small that they cannot be filtered out during the waste water treatment process.

Answer (score -1):

All the sentences are grammatically correct, but I do have a few comments:

- The sentences on the left are more concise, I would prefer them over the sentences on the right, even though both are correct and have the same meaning.
- Sentences 1, 3 and 5 (left) use active voice, while 2, 4 and 6 (left) use passive voice.  (All the sentences on the right use active voice.)  Usually active voice is preferred, but passive voice is acceptable in most settings.
- Sentences 1, 3 and 5 (right) sound unnatural, probably because you added "we".  It seems like these sentences have a lot of extra words and can be made simpler.

A few additional, unrelated notes

- I'm assuming "filterout" in sentence 5 is supposed to be "filter out."  Use two separate words.
- "Wastewater" is a compound word with no space in between.

Comment: •The sentences on the left are more concise, I would prefer them over the sentences on the left,- What do you mean by "them" in this sentence? I am confused.

Comment: I think the poster meant to say that the concise sentences on the left are preferable to those on the _right_!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it has been fixed.